# Add input validation to html input in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex, validation

Having this input:

```
const REGEX_EMAIL_VALIDATION = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

...

<input
   pattern={REGEX_EMAIL_VALIDATION}
   type="email"
   value={field.value || ''}
   onChange={(e) => handleChangeEmail(id, e)}
/>
```

I've tried like this but it seems to let any input, it doesn't verify the pattern.

I would like to show a message while the user types the input if the value is not correct. In this case - if it doesn't have email shape.

Comment: did you try out my answer? Consider giving some feedback

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionaly render an error message based on testing against your regular expression (`RegEx.test(value) ? true : false`).

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState(""); // state value for email
  const REGEX_EMAIL_VALIDATION = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value); // set email to value from input
  }
  
  // render
  return (
    <div>
      <input name="email" value={email} onChange={handleEmailChange}></input>
      {
        REGEX_EMAIL_VALIDATION.test(email) ? <small>valid</small> : <small>invalid</small>
      }
      <p>{email}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try it out in [this Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-yonath-pbyvy?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
const re =
  /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  if (re.test(e.target.value)) {
    // this is a valid email address
    // call setState({email: email}) to update the email
    // or update the data in redux store.
  } else {
    // invalid email, maybe show an error to the user.
  }
};
```